# Select duas tabelas

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Boa tarde! por favor não estou conseguindo fazer um select

Tenho duas tabelas no banco (campanha e campanha_cliques)

Preciso selecionar somente os resultados que estiver com o tipo=2 da tabela (CAMPANHA) e ao mesmo tempo verificar se na tabela campanha_cliques no campo id_usuario não estiver o id do usuario

quero mostrar somentes os dados de quem ainda nao está no campo id_usuario da tabela campanha_cliques

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  c.id,
  c.site,
  c.cliques_usados,
  c.cliques,
  c.localizacao,
  c.tipo,
  c.id_user
FROM
  campanha c
INNER JOIN campanha_cliques p
WHERE p.tipo = '2' 
  AND p.id_usuario != '$uiddw'
```

tentei isso mais nao funciona

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E o que relaciona a tabela campanha com a tabela campanha_cliques? Ou você quer apenas o produto cartesiano das duas tabelas?

Comment: Consegui resolver obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  c.id,
  c.site,
  c.cliques_usados,
  c.cliques,
  c.localizacao,
  c.tipo,
  c.id_user
FROM
  campanha c
INNER JOIN campanha_cliques p
ON c.id = p.id_campanha
WHERE p.tipo = '2' 
  AND p.id_usuario != '$uiddw'
```

Acredito que só o que falta é o ON que normalmente é utilizado pra fazer a ligação entre as tabelas envolvidas no `JOIN`.

Comment: Ainda não funciona!

Tipo vou explicar melhor, preciso pegar os dados da tabela "CAMPANHA" com o tipo=2 que nao tenha o id_usuario e id_campanha na tabela CAMPANHA_CLIQUES..

quero mostrar somente os dados que nao tenha ainda na tabela campanha_cliques.

Comment: consegui, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta está meio confusa mas talvez seja:

```
SELECT 
  c.id,
  c.site,
  c.cliques_usados,
  c.cliques,
  c.localizacao,
  c.tipo,
  c.id_user
FROM campanha c 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM campanha_cliques p WHERE p.tipo = '2' AND p.id_usuario == c.id_user);
```

ou ainda:

```
SELECT 
  c.id,
  c.site,
  c.cliques_usados,
  c.cliques,
  c.localizacao,
  c.tipo,
  c.id_user
FROM campanha c LEFT OUTER JOIN campanha_cliques p ON (p.id_usuario == c.id_user)
WHERE p.tipo = '2' AND p.id_usuario IS NULL;
```

Comment: consegui, obrigado

Comment: E o que era? É bom ficar documentada a solução para que vier a pesquisar.

Answer (score 0):

Me corrija se eu tiver entendido errado:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
  c.id,
  c.site,
  c.cliques_usados,
  c.cliques,
  c.localizacao,
  c.tipo,
  c.id_user
FROM
  campanha c
LEFT JOIN campanha_cliques p on p.id_campanha = p.campanha
WHERE p.tipo = '2' 
  AND c.id_user = '$uiddw'
  AND p.i_campanha is null
```

Este select retornará os dados da tabela `campanha` com `tipo = 2`, `id_user = '$uiddw'`, onde NÃO existam registros equivalentes na `campanha_cliques`.

É isso?

Comment: consegui, obrigado

Comment: Se essa ou qualquer uma das respostas tiver sido útil, dê um upvote. Se alguma tiver sido a resposta correta, marque como correta. Se não, poste a solução e depois marque sua resposta como correta. Isso tudo ajuda futuros usuários que tiverem uma dúvida parecida.